# how to solve the equation $\tan^2(2x)+2\tan(2x) \cdot \tan(3x)-1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How to solve the equation $$\tan^2(2x)+2\tan(2x) \cdot \tan(3x)-1=0$$

Can anyone give some hints in this question ?

Comment: You want value of x

Answer (score 4):

Using $\tan2B=\dfrac{2\tan B}{1-\tan^2B,}$

$$\tan3x=\dfrac{1-\tan^22x}{2\tan2x}=\dfrac1{\tan2\cdot2x}=\cot4x=\tan\left(\dfrac\pi2-4x\right)$$

Now $\tan y=\tan A\implies y=n\pi+A$ where $n$ is any integer

Comment: The formula for tan $3x$ is wrong.  Multiplying both sides by tan(4x), you would get tan3x*tan4x = 1 for all $x$, which is clearly absurd.

Comment: @Alex, Its not formula for $$\tan3x$$ but a rearrangement of the given equation   and why "absurd"?

Comment: Oops, I misread your question.  I thought you were claiming this was true for all x.  Sorry.  I'll upvote your answer.

Comment: p.s., if going by what the OP wrote, you would have $\tan3x = \frac{1-\tan^2(2x)}{2\tan(2x)}$: you might wanna edit that into your post.

Comment: @Alex, Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for saying it's absurd.

Comment: @Alex, But I'm really happy that you tried to understand my method & felt free to share your feedback

Answer (score 0):

Let $t$ = tan $x$.  Using [trig](http://www.sosmath.com/trig/Trig5/trig5/trig5.html), we can see that tan $2x = \frac{2t}{1-t^2},$ and tan $3x = t\frac{3-t^2}{1-3t^2}$.

Then the equation becomes:

$$\frac{4t^2}{(1-t^2)^2} + 2\frac{2t^2(3-t^2)}{(1-t^2)(1-3t^2)} - 1 = 0$$

Multiply by the GCD, which is $(1-t^2)^2(1-3t^2)$ to get

$$(4t^2)(1-3t^2) + 4t^2(3-t^2)(1-t^2) - (1-t^2)^2(1-3t^2) = 0$$

Expand, and solve for $t$, and then take the arctangent.

Answer (score 0):

After converting all terms to $\tan(x)$ and substituting it as $t$ you get an equation which is $7t^6-35t^4+21t^2-1=0$ put $t^2=x$ you get a cubic which needs to be solved hope you can take from there.